# How to check logged user's role in Laravel 5.8 with route filters

Tags: php, laravel

I need to add some thing like this to check the user's role accessing the urls in a route group.

When adding this, I got `Attribute [filter] does not exist` error.

Do I need to add anything else in the controller?

```
Route::filter('role', function()
{ 
  if ( Auth::user()->role !==1) {
     // do something
     return Redirect::to('/'); 
   }
}); 

Route::group(array('before' => 'role'), function() {            
Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');
Route::delete('/users/delete', 'UsersController@destroy');
});
```

My `UsersController`, do I need to add any extra code?

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {       
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us each line is pointed when you got this error?

Comment: Route::filter was added in router web.php, the user controller request add as group as you can see above. When i placed the Route filter inn the web.php the error is poited in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar.php ."Attribute [filter] does not exist."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `Route::filter()` was wiped away from Laravel since > 5.0, so it is trying to find an unexisting `Route::$filter` static property.

Right now (version 5.8 as I am writing this), the best way to do that filtering is to use [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware).

An example below:

### `app/Http/Middleware/CheckRole.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;
use Redirect;

class CheckRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role !== 1) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```php
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // Other middlewares...    

    'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
];
```

### `web.php`

```php
Route->group(['middleware' => 'role'], function() {            
    Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');
    Route::delete('/users/delete', 'UsersController@destroy');
});
```

---

I guess you can also attribute the middleware directly in your controller's constructor instead of attributing it in the route list:

```php
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {       
        $this->middleware('role');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I got this error Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\dineapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php

Comment: i think we have to add this  Route::group(array('before' => 'role'), function() {            

});  on add this it give "Call to a member function middleware() on null"

Comment: Sorry, `Route::middleware` needs to be called before `Route::group`. I edited my post.

Comment: I got an erro on that Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Router::group() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\dineapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 237

Comment: Well... I have two solutions in mind. Tell me if `Route::middleware(['role'])->group(...)` is working. If not, try `Route::group(['middleware' => 'role'], function() {...});`.

Comment: ples edit this line Route::middleware('role')->group so that it wil be a great help for others

Comment: No problem, just tell me which solution is actually working in order for me to edit my answer and share the right one.

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => 'role'], function() { 
Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UsersController@edit');
Route::delete('/users/delete', 'UsersController@destroy'); 
});  this one